# How to load model in opencart 3.0?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3, opencart-3

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function preDemo1() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/catalog/controller/prerecorded/preDemo.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerPrerecordedPreDemo->insertData() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerStartupRouter->index() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/system/engine/router.php(67): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/system/engine/router.php(56): Router->execute(Object(Action)) #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/system/framework.php(168): Router->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) #6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/system/startup.php(104): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/index.php(19): start('catalog') #8 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/epos/catalog/controller/prerecorded/preDemo.php on line 43

#  Controller

```
public function insertData(){
        // print_r($_POST);exit;

        if($this->request->post['name'] && $this->request->post['email'] && $this->request->post['contactNumber'] && $this->request->post['businessType'] && $this->request->post['businessName'] && $this->request->post['role'] ) {

$data = array(
$name = $this->request->post['name'],
$email = $this->request->post['email'],
$contactNumber = $this->request->post['contactNumber'],
$businessType = $this->request->post['businessType'],
$businessName = $this->request->post['businessName'],
$role = $this->request->post['role']);
} 

else {
$name = 0;
}
// echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
$this->load->model('prerecorded/preDemo');
$this->preDemo->preDemo1($data);



    }
```

#  Model ##########

```
<?php
class ModelPrerecordedPreDemo extends Model {
    public function preDemo1($data) {

        $this->db->insert("",$data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

correct load function from model:

```
$this->prerecorded_preDemo->preDemo1($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a naming problem with your model. File name an the class inside the file much match. You're also not following the file naming conventions of CodeIgniter.

The model file `preDemo.php` should probably be named `Pre_demo.php` and be declared like this

```
class Pre_demo extends Model {
```

With that done the model should load successfully (which it clearly does not in your code).

```
$this->load->model('prerecorded/pre_demo');
$this->pre_demo->preDemo1($data);
```